# Use result from one query in another query

Tags: php, jquery, sql, smarty

i have 2 tables ( featured , posts )

Featured table contains columns ( PID , Price)
Posts table contains columns (USERID , PID)

i want to get the (sum) of (price in featured) to the (USERID in columns)

i used this Code in PHP file

```
$query="SELECT sum(price) AS fp FROM featured LEFT JOIN posts ON
featured.PID=posts.PID AND   posts.USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['USERID'])."' ";
$executequery=$conn->execute($query);
$fp = $executequery->fields['fp'];
STemplate::assign('fp',$fp);
```

and in the tpl file i call it by

```
<div class="val">
               <span>
               <em>${$fp}</em>
               </span>
               </div>
```

and nothing come out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Query :

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0329a/4)**

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS FP FROM posts as P
LEFT JOIN featured as F ON F.PID=P.PID 
WHERE P.USERID=2
```

Modification:

```
$query="SELECT SUM(Price) AS FP FROM posts as P LEFT JOIN featured as F ON F.PID=P.PID 
WHERE P.USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['USERID'])."' ";
$executequery=$conn->execute($query);
$fp = $executequery->fields['FP'];
STemplate::assign('FP',$fp);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="val">
    <span>
        <em>${$fp}</em>
    </span>
</div>
```